# exec: "php-fpm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: php, docker, centos7

Getting below error while running docker-compose up -d for laravel Project.

```
ERROR: for groshop_laravel-env_1  Cannot start service laravel-env: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "php-fpm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for laravel-env  Cannot start service laravel-env: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "php-fpm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My dockerFile looks like

```
FROM centos:7

# Install some must-haves
RUN yum -y install vim wget sendmail
RUN yum -y install libtool make automake autoconf nasm libpng-static
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git --version

# Install PHP 7.1 on CentOS
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
    && rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum install yum-utils
RUN yum install epel-release
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73

RUN yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 -y install php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-gd php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring \
    php-mysqlnd php-pear php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zip

RUN php -v

# Prepare PHP environment
COPY config/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.conf
COPY config/php/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY config/php/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
RUN composer --version

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
RUN yum -y install nodejs
RUN yum list installed nodejs
RUN node -v

# Final update and clean up
RUN yum -y update --skip-broken
RUN yum clean all

# Define work directory
WORKDIR /var/www/laravel-boilerplate

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 9000

# CMD ["php-fpm", "-F", "-O"]
CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

Also i have php files under config. have tried CMD line with changes but no luck.
Any idea?
Also one other observation i looked at is, i couldnt see those php-fpm.* files under /etc but only supervisord.conf file with below content.

> [supervisord] nodaemon=true
>
> [program:php-fpm] command=/usr/sbin/php-fpm -F -R user = root
> autostart = true stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
> stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot spot the `php-fpm` package being installed.

```
RUN yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 -y install php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-gd php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring \
    php-mysqlnd php-pear php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zip php-fpm
```

Comment: you can also remove the "php" package (which is "mod_php", so not needed if you use FPM)